# Why do molecules in a gas not generally arrange themselves at the distance of minimum potential energy (Lennard-Jones 6-12 potential)

Tags: potential-energy, ideal-gas, equilibrium

As the title suggests, why is this?

Is it because the distance of molecules in a gas is too large (compared to in liquids/solids)? Or are there other reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of equilibrium is characterised by a minimum in free energy $F=U-TS$ (Helmholtz for simplicity), not a minimum in potential energy.

What this means is that while the system is indeed attempting to minimise the potential energy $U$, it is simultaneously trying to maximise the entropy $S$. The balance, i.e. which term dominates, is determined by the temperature $T$.

At high temperatures, entropy (which favours spaced out, randomly disordered atoms) dominates. This can also be understood from an atomistic perspective: at high temperatures, the atoms are randomly jiggling at high velocities and therefore have a tendency to break any bonds that form.